# Write json strings using java (JSP)

Tags: java, json

I want to create a json string like below.

```
"data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "data": "one",
    "color": "008ee4"
},{
    "id": "2",
    "data": "two",
    "color": "008ee4"
}]
```

So far I have come up with this.

```
<%
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray innerArray = new JSONArray();

innerObject.put("label", "1");
innerObject.put("value", "one");
innerObject.put("color", "008ee4");

outerObject.put("data", outerArray);

System.out.println(outerObject.toString());
%>
```

And it gives the output like

```
{"data":[]}
```

I want to remove those curly brackets and input data inside square brackets. Please help me.

UPDATE

```
 {
    type: "line",
    renderAt: "chartContainer1",
    width: "500",
    height: "300",
    dataFormat: "json",
    "dataSource":  {
"chart": {
    "caption": "Total Revenues from 2008-2013",
    "numberprefix": "$",
    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
    "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
    "plotbordercolor": "008ee4",
    "plotborderthickness": "3",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
    "showcanvasborder": "0",
    "tooltipbgcolor": "00396d",
    "tooltipcolor": "FFFFFF",
    "tooltipbordercolor": "00396d",
    "numdivlines": "2",
    "yaxisvaluespadding": "20",
    "anchorbgcolor": "008ee4",
    "anchorborderthickness": "0",
    "showshadow": "0",
    "anchorradius": "4",
    "chartrightmargin": "25",
    "canvasborderalpha": "0",
    "showborder": "0"
},



"data": [
    {
        "label": "2009",
        "value": "4400000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2010",
        "value": "4800000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2011",
        "value": "5500000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2012",
        "value": "6700000",
        "color": "008ee4",
        "anchorradius": "7",
        "tooltext": "Historical high"
    },
    {
        "label": "2013",
        "value": "4200000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    }
]
}
 }
```

Above is the main json file. I just want to replace the data part with my data.

Comment: It looks like it's outputting exactly what you told it to. You just need to do more put statements. Also, you should parse the JSON file and store ***it*** as `outerObject`.

Comment: You're missing `outerArray.put(innerObject)`. And a loop, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
    JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray innerArray = new JSONArray();


    innerObject = new JSONObject();
    innerObject.put("label", "1");
    innerObject.put("value", "one");
    innerObject.put("color", "008ee4");

    innerArray.add(innerObject);
    outerObject.put("data", innerArray);

    System.out.println(outerObject.toString());
```